# elasticsearch subtract numeric fields between two datasets

Tags: elasticsearch

Some statistical data present, the task is to display for timespan latest value and delta (initial value - latest value).

Is there any way how this can be done via elasticsearch, not running 2 queries and making subtraction manually?

For instance, we have this data:

```
{
 downloads: 100,
 purchases: 100,
 data: '01/01/2014'
},
{
 downloads: 120,
 purchases: 120,
 data: '01/02/2014'
}
```

And timespan specified is `01/01/2014` - `01/02/2014`

Query should return all data for `01/02/2014`, 20 as delta for downloads and 20 as delta for purchases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use date histogram aggregations with nested stats aggregation and manually calculate difference from result.

You could explore this gist https://gist.github.com/mikeasick/8734117